# Is there any reason why Google is not classifying Python as a programming language in Google Trends?

Tags: python, google-trends

It seems Python cannot be searched in Google Trends as a programming language topic. [It is possible to do this for R, C, C++, Javascript, Java, etc.](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=Python,%2Fm%2F0212jm,%2Fm%2F01t6b,%2Fm%2F07sbkfb,%2Fm%2F0jgqg)

I find this very odd. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I tried this again and [it is possible now](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=%2Fm%2F05z1_,%2Fm%2F0212jm,%2Fm%2F01t6b,%2Fm%2F07sbkfb,%2Fm%2F0jgqg)

Comment: you could at least post a link and screenshot...

Comment: @Dmitry Yes sorry, I had it ready and I forgot about it

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with a massive search base over python snakes and monty python and other non related programming stuff, whereas in c++ that can't happen

Comment: @Isac Well, that for me would be a good reason for adding this class. I find it hard to believe that their deep/machine learning or whatever algorithms they use won't detect this class.